# Click button getting error : unrecognized selector sent to instance - IOS Swift 3

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift3

Click button getting error : unrecognized selector sent to instance - IOS Swift 3

```
import UIKit
class Login: UIViewController {
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func LoginButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    print("Login button")
}}
```

Error 
2017-04-05 14:55:56.965 Design[3510:67974] Unknown class Login in Interface Builder file.
2017-04-05 14:56:00.084 Design[3510:67974] -[UIView LoginButton:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ffa2f70c9b0
2017-04-05 14:56:00.093 Design[3510:67974] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView LoginButton:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ffa2f70c9b0'
*** First throw call stack:
(
....
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Image :
[image]
I am beginner in IOS app development

Comment: Have you assigend your class to the your viewcontroller?

Comment: your target is invalid

Comment: Try removing the action and adding it again.

Comment: @iPeter yes i did ,its 2nd screen in my Main.storyBoard

Comment: @Sneha I did it many times.

Comment: Check connection is storyboard and be sure there is only one connecton for this button.Show storyboard button connection image.

Comment: @TusharSharma i checked there is only connection

Comment: Have you given your controller the name of your file.? As it also says -: Unknown class Login in Interface Builder file.

Comment: @Sneha - are you seen this `i did ,its 2nd screen in my`, how to access the second VC methd in first VC

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik I didn get u

Comment: @Sneha - check the screen shot it shows class name as manual in the place of automatic

Comment: @rkkanojia7: How did you connect the action? By dragging in the class or by dragging from button to the panel in left?

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik, I can see in you image that you have not used **present** you are using **push**. Please check your storyboard

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik ss was added later....then that's the issue I guess

Comment: check how many actions are connected to the button if more than one are connected then it is also looking for a method that is not available in the code. Try removing all the actions on the button and dragging from the code to the button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved Thanks to everyone, Problem was when i am making connection - On object selection there was to 2 options First VC controller "Login" and second one only "Login" (default selecting). I just changed defualt "Login" to VC "Login".

[image: Default object]

[image: 2 types of options]

[image: After selected VC Login]

Answer (score 2):

You must be check the classname and module. If the module is displayed in place holder or Empty.Click the module check box and dropdown will be displayed with your app name now you will select the option.And give the Storyboard id. Now run your coding.

[image]

Comment: I had this issue.  The module was not selected.  Selecting it fixed this issue for me.

Comment: Super happy coding

Answer (score 1):

You most likely forgot to set your custom view controller class to match the one you created in the storyboard

If you already set your custom view controller class than reset that and remove IBAction connection and reconnect it.

Answer (score 1):

Got your problem you have not included navigation controller in your storyboard and you are trying to push from segue. But you have posted the code for button action. Add navigation controller to your storyboard first. Remove manual segue from login button to any storyboard.

If you don't know how to add navigation bar the follow the image: 
[image]

Comment: we can use present , check the screen shot it shows class name as manual in the place of automatic

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik For more info , In my Main.storyborad have 2 screen on click first one go to second (Login screen) , after some logic success only condition. So form first to go second working fine but in 2nd screen (Login) button actions not working.

Comment: @rkkanojia7 - is this possible to attach your project

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik, I can see in you image that you have not used **present** you are using **push**. Please check your storyboard

Comment: @BasirAlam - oh sorry , but problem not in segue, problem in connection

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik Sorry not possible , i can explain what i am doing....have 2 screen on click first screen button there is condition if true then go 2nd screen and then same 2nd screen some button logic will go 3rd one. If your have any example/tutorial/code on swift 3 please share.

Comment: @rkkanojia7 - then follow basir answer

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik its solved thanks for your time , when i making connection there is option "object" where is showing 2 option, one i know is VC other don't know, i just make it with VC and working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try to reconnect @IBAction Method

```
@IBAction func LoginButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        print("Login button")
}
```

and if it's not working can you please show image of your Stroyboard and connection that you have done with your button

Comment: are you seen this `yes i did ,its 2nd screen`, in comments

Comment: Added image please check

Comment: For the experiment disconnect this method and add new method then check it that it's working or not

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by going to the "Show the Connections inspector" when you have the button selected[here is my weather app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rBC69.png). Take away any connections from the button there and start again!